# Cocoa pods stuck while cloning

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I try to set up cocoa pods in my MacBook Pro El Capitan.

`pod setup` command will stuck on **Cloning into 'master'...**

Even I waited for 2 hours with 1GB download of `git-remote-https`.

It is never completed.

I also tried lots of time on Google for last 15 days.

I also tried following commands:

```
pod repo remove master
```

It says master repository not found.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue ? I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

**That bypass / workaround solution works just to Virtual Machines**

When you try to install cocoa pod, there is no network activity after it gets stuck.
According to hagge's comment on March 8, 2016 (https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/4989), this kind of problem can be caused by automatic limitation of transfer rate on servers, which is done to make sure that extremely high levels of load do not bring problems.
If you are using VMware or Virtualized Machines, you can proceed as below.

Change the configuration of Virtual Machine:

1. Select Network Adapter
2. Go to Advanced Settings
3. Incoming Transfer, set to Cable Mbps (4000 Kbps)
4. Outgoing Transfer, set to Cable Mbps (4000 Kbps)
5. Click OK

You may have to make the command install more than once. It'll take time but may work. Worked for me!

[image: How to proceed (Image)]

Answer (score 1):

Its not a cloning problem. Your Internet connection problem. To solve this issue, you have to go to VM(virtual machine) settings to Bridge the physical connection.

**VMware Player-->Removable Devices-->Network Adapter-->settings**

You will find Network connection and check both

choose the option **Bridged: Connected directly to the physical network**

if you are using a laptop

**Enable Replicate physical network connection state.**

99% will be work